# Using C++ template as return type/variable name

Tags: c++, templates, arduino

I'm trying to use the template `StaticJsonDocument` from the arduino-json library in a function and return it, but I can't figure out what exactly I'm supposed to write into the return type's argument list.. everything i tried gets rejected as invalid.

```
StaticJsonDocument<???> toJson(char* c) {

  StaticJsonDocument<256> doc;
  deserializeJson(doc, c);

  return doc;
}
```

Definition of `StaticJsonDocument`from Github:

```
#pragma once

#include "JsonDocument.hpp"

namespace ARDUINOJSON_NAMESPACE {

template <size_t desiredCapacity>
class StaticJsonDocument : public JsonDocument {
  static const size_t _capacity =
      AddPadding<Max<1, desiredCapacity>::value>::value;

 public:
  StaticJsonDocument() : JsonDocument(_buffer, _capacity) {}

  StaticJsonDocument(const StaticJsonDocument& src)
      : JsonDocument(_buffer, _capacity) {
    set(src);
  }

  template <typename T>
  StaticJsonDocument(const T& src,
                     typename enable_if<IsVisitable<T>::value>::type* = 0)
      : JsonDocument(_buffer, _capacity) {
    set(src);
  }

  // disambiguate
  StaticJsonDocument(VariantRef src) : JsonDocument(_buffer, _capacity) {
    set(src);
  }

  StaticJsonDocument operator=(const StaticJsonDocument& src) {
    set(src);
    return *this;
  }

  template <typename T>
  StaticJsonDocument operator=(const T& src) {
    set(src);
    return *this;
  }

 private:
  char _buffer[_capacity];
};

}  // namespace ARDUINOJSON_NAMESPACE
```

Comment: Since you return `StaticJsonDocument<256> doc;`, maybe write `256`?

Comment: dont know where you are coming from, but note that c++ templates are by no means similar to java generics. `StaticJsonDocument` is the template, while `StaticJsonDocument<256>` is just a type like any other, and note that usually `SomeTemplate<256>` is a type completely unrelated to `SomeTemplate<42>`. Hence if you return a `StaticJsonDocument<256>` then thats your return type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that `doc` is a `StaticJsonDocument<256>`, *that's* the function return type.

Although in later C++ standards (C++14 onwards), you can write

`auto toJson(char* c) {`

and let the compiler figure it out for you.